# MongoDB override or skip existing document with Unique Index

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, database-indexes

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Data. Also, I have a collection in MongoDB. The collection contains a few fields and I created an index with the UNIQUE flag by 3 fields, for example: name + surname + age.

When I insert documents with the following Java format `repository.saveAll(list)`, and my collection already contains part of these documents - Mongo throws an Exception in my face like:

> Bulk write operation error on server localhost. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: myCollection.name index: name_1_surname_1_age_1 dup key

It's expected behavior, but I need to configure Mongo with the following logic:

- When inserting multiple documents, and the index says "some documents already exist in the collection" - ignore such documents, or skip them, or just override without any exceptions.

Is it possible? It's important for me to do it with multiple documents at the same time.

Do you have some idea how to do this? As a better result, I would like to use some properties or additional flag without custom queries.
Thanks.

Comment: What does "skip" mean? Provide some context. Why don't you use `try catch` and ignore the `Exception`?

Comment: @BenjaminM updated descriptions, thanks.
I can do this with your approach, but all documents will be processed one by one, thus there will be "n" requests for documents with size "n", but I would like to do this at the configuration level and with a single request for all documents

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have an unique index and I'm trying to upsert documents as: Insert new ones, and skip existing ones.

Documentation is missing this or doesn't say it explicitely, but you need to set up `ordered: false`. In this case it will continue with operations and return list of exceptions at the end.

```rb
MyModel.collection.bulk_write(
  [
    { update_one: { filter: {...}, update: { '$set' => {...}, upsert: true } },
    { update_one: { filter: {...}, update: { '$set' => {...}, upsert: true } },
    { update_one: { filter: {...}, update: { '$set' => {...}, upsert: true } },
    ...
  ],
  ordered: false
)
```

And at the end you will get back error like this:

```
Multiple errors:
[11000]: E11000 duplicate key error collection: my_database.my_collection index: my_unique_index dup key: { ... };
[11000]: E11000 duplicate key error collection: my_database.my_collection index: my_unique_index dup key: { ... };
(Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError)
```

> I had to format that output a bit coz otherwise it comes as a single long line. Also my sample is in Ruby, but it should be same everywhere.

I'm not sure if this is desired behavior or a side-effect, but it works.